# User named "Azure Boards" in Azure Devops org

Tags: azure-devops

In hardening our ADO projects for security, we found that an org-level user named "Azure Boards" has been granted access to all area paths. We haven't yet found documentation on this user, so we're assuming that this is a built-in user that should not be altered. However, as part of hardening we do need to understand more about this user.

The question is: Where is the documentation for the org-level ADO user named Azure Boards (if any)?

Update per comment request:

[image]

Comment: Hi GaTech,
I cannot found the user Azure Boards in my org, do you mind sharing some screenshot of this user info?

Comment: We have two different orgs, and I'm only seeing it when I set area path root permissions in projects in those orgs. It's a member of Security Service Group.

Comment: There are a few [user accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#user-accounts) that are generated by the system to support specific operations, such as Agent Pool Service, PipelinesSDK, ProjectName Build Service and Project Collection Build Service, I cannot see the account Azure Boards in the Security Service Group, could you please open the Security Service Group in the org settings and enter the account Azure Boards in the filter, then kindly share a screenshot in the issue description?

Comment: Thanks - updated the description with requested image.

Comment: Hi @GaTechThomas, I have updated the answer, please check it. I can see the account Azure Boards after I connect Azure Boards to GitHub.

Comment: Hi @GaTechThomas, Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find doc to describe this service account, I have raised a new [feedback ticket](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/9139) in the GitHub and report it to Microsoft Doc teams, you can follow the ticket to get the latest news, I will continue to check the ticket and If have any achievements, I will inform you here.

**Update1**

This account Azure Boards gets created when you connect Azure Boards to GitHub. It works in the background to support the features that the GitHub connection supports.